# Subtraction 8-bit binary number

Tags: math, binary, twos-complement

I'm trying to add up two 8 bit numbers which one is negative and second one is positive. Here it is what I do:

```
92-113
```

so I represent each number as binary

```
92 - 01011100
113 - 01110001
```

after changing 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 I get :

```
10001110 and after adding 1 I have 1000111 which is -113
```

then I'm adding them up and I get :

```
11101011
```

what totally makes no sense, what I probably do wrongly ? Would really love to know where I make mistake as it's really basic knowledge ;/

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? What would make a sense in your opinion?

Comment: `11101011` = `0xEB` = `-21`, which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything - `11101011` is the binary equivalent of -21 (92-113) in 8-bit signed binary.

For singed integer types, the left=most bit determine if the number is positive or negative.  To get the additive inverse, you flip all bits but the rightmost.  It;s the same process you used to convert 113 to -113.

Doing that yields `00010101` which is 21. So `11101011` is -21.